# ruby shorter array iteration

Tags: arrays, ruby, colorize

I'm trying to find out if there is a shorter way to do the below code:

```
$my_array.each do |eh|
  row = Array.new
  eh.each do |k,v|
    if  k == 'state'
      if eh[k] ==  "stopped"
         row << eh[k].red
      elsif eh[k] ==  "running"
         row << eh[k].green
      else 
        row << eh[k].yellow
      end 
    else
     row << eh[k] 
    end 
  end 
  data << row 
end
```

The above is for the use of `terminal-table` and `colorize`

Comment: Add a sample data array to make others life easier while testing solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
color_map = { 'stopped' => :red, 'running' => :green }
data = $my_array.map do |eh|
  eh.map do |k,v|
    if  k == 'state'
      v.send color_map.fetch(v, :yellow)
    else
      v 
    end 
  end 
end
```

It uses `map` instead of `each` to avoid building the arrays manually. It also uses a hash to map the state to the colour instead of using if-statements.

You could take it further and remove the inner `if` statement if you like, but this is at least an improvement.

Comment: Great answer. With the [colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize) gem, though, you can do `v.colorize(color)` instead of `v.send(color)`, which I think is a little clearer. You might also use `color_map.default = :yellow` at the top instead of using `color_map.fetch(v, :yellow)` so all of the color information is in the same place.